# Zoom out on small screen in website already responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a problem with a small screen size.I have created a website that is responsive using bootstrap,but **I have a problem with a table that has a lot of data which means the table is large.**

**Example:**

[image: EXAMPLE LARGE TABLE]

**Mobile Device**

I DONT WANT BE LIKE THIS :

[image: TABLE MOBILE DEVICE1]

[image: TABLE ON MOBILE DEVICE]

Can you just zoom out on a large table? not with other content just the table that can be zoom out

Comment: i just using this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: its still same, its because iam using bootstrap class table table-responsive @Aetheris

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp maybe this kind of trick? Hopefully that helps? (just not on hover but always)